# How do I highlight text or formulas?

Tags: formatting, errors, color, line-breaking, bugs

I want to highlight newlined sentences and formulas. The following code will allow me to highlight newlined sentences, but I get an error if they contain quotations (`\cite`) or formulas (`\begin{equation}`).

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Latex 2023

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\ctext}[3][RGB]{%
  \begingroup
  \definecolor{hlcolor}{#1}{#2}\sethlcolor{hlcolor}%
  \hl{#3}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so we've got a compilable example of the problem.

Comment: You cold use `tizmark` for highlighting. But, as @cfr correctly mentions, a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) would be nice to have.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what 'newlined' means?

Comment: Sorry. I was using "newlined" to mean a multi-line sentence with line breaks.

Comment: You could use something like `tcolorbox` as an alternative to highlighting for multi-line maths. That would also work for block-style quotations and needn't look like a box. It could just be a shaded background. A complete example would make it easier for people to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use cites or equations inside `\hl`. The issue with cites can be solved with a `\mbox{\cite{...}}` at least in some cases (no MWE, not possible to check if that could work in your case), but that will not work for equations.

An alternative is to compile with `lualatex` and `biber` with a preamble like this:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}      
\usepackage{luacolor}  
\usepackage{lua-ul}      
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{yourbib.bib}
```

And then you can use code like ...

```
\highLight[cyan!30]{foo \cite{yourcite} foo}
```

... as well as ...

```
\highLight[olive!10]{
foo 
    \begin{equation} 
        foo 
    \end{equation}
foo
}
```

With a result like this:

[image]